# FATAL ERROR: call_and_retry_last allocation failed - javascript heap out of memory, adding npm memory doesn't fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, error-handling, runtime-error

I am getting some massive error whenever I try to write only certain images. Let me elaborate. I have code that takes 2 different images, and adds one image onto the other, using jimp. Sometimes, it works. But with other files(I have no reason why some images work and some dont), I get this error.

I have already tried using npm increase-memory-limit. It stated it worked in npm, but failed immediately after.

constants:

- I'm using repl.it to host the app locally
- I'm using nodejs
- I'm using jimp for the image combination

The error: I'll just paste the whole thing here.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[163:0x29b9520]    35500 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 210.9 (222.4) -> 210.9 (213.7) MB, 243.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.820, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested
[163:0x29b9520]    35765 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 210.9 (213.7) -> 210.9 (213.4) MB, 265.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.675, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa673d8 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x95bb2e  [node]
 3: 0xc73b32 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xc73ec7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xe31465  [node]
 6: 0xe48e64 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 7: 0xe0a0a0 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 8: 0xe04abc v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawArray(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
 9: 0xe04b94 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Oddball>, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
10: 0x1079f8d v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NumberDictionary> v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NumberDictionary, v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::New<v8::internal::Isolate>(v8::internal::Isolate*, int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::MinimumCapacity) [node]
11: 0x107a216 v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NumberDictionary> v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NumberDictionary, v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::EnsureCapacity<v8::internal::Isolate>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NumberDictionary>, int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
12: 0x107aaa0 v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NumberDictionary> v8::internal::Dictionary<v8::internal::NumberDictionary, v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::Add<v8::internal::Isolate>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::NumberDictionary>, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyDetails, v8::internal::InternalIndex*) [node]
```

Never seen this error before. Now for my code:

```
jimp.read(req.file.buffer, (err, fir_img) => {
                                   //replace with req.file.buffer
                                  if(err) {
                                      console.log(err);
                                      res.send({status: "error"})                     

                                  } else {
                                      jimp.read(file10.location[0], (err, sec_img) => {
                                          if(err) {
                                              console.log(err);
                                            res.send({status: "error"})
                                          } else {
                                              fir_img.composite( sec_img, x, y);
                                             //it breaks trying to write the new image
                                              fir_img.write('new_imgae16.png');
```

Sorry for the formatting. Assume all brackets are proper.
What it does: Takes an inputted image, and then takes another generated in code image that is of a qr code, and it combines them into one image. The inputted image is what changes. With some inputted images it works, and with some it doesnt. Trying to write the new image breaks it.

No clue at all as to why some images work and some don't. Can't be random, but the images are practically identitcal and the same # of pixels, both png's.

Once again, I've tried extending the memory via npm, but it didn't work.

Any help is great. Thanks, and goodluck!

Comment: Simple: your OS ran out of RAM. Replit places hard constraints on your memory usage, which is pretty low, so if you don't want to pay I suggest running this on your own computer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it appears that you are trying to read an image from a buffer (req.file.buffer) and another image from a file path (file10.location[0]), then you are using the Jimp library to composite the two images and write the new image to a file called 'new_imgae16.png'.

The error message you provided suggests that the program is running out of memory. One thing that can cause this is that the image from the buffer is too large and it's causing the program to run out of memory when trying to composite it with the second image.

You can try resizing the images before manipulating them by using the .resize() function in Jimp.

Another approach is to try breaking down your code into smaller chunks, so it doesn't have to handle large images all at once.

You can also try using a stream-based library like "stream-transform" to process large images in chunks, this way you are not loading the entire image into memory at once.

It's also possible that you have a memory leak in your code, in this case, you can use heapdump package to take a heap snapshot and inspect it to identify the cause of the memory leak.

Also, you can try using the --max_old_space_size flag when starting your script. For example, running "node --max_old_space_size=4096 script.js" will allocate up to 4GB of memory for the Node.js process.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try them all. One thing though, how do I use max_old_space size flag thing? Not sure what you mean. 

Do I run in npm:

npm --max_old_space_size=4096 index.js

Or add that at the top of index.js itself?